# Is the `std::exception`, in its current form, redundant?

Tags: c++, exception

Usually, when I want to create my own exception, I inherit from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error`.

Is there anything that stops me from creating my own empty "tag-class"?

```
class out_of_bounds_access {}; // or:
class memory_leak {};
```

and throw just that? 
After all, mostly, it's the class-name that carries information about what went wrong not the members of the exception class.

**Ok, so I assumed this is a bad idea, but why? Why is this a bad idea?**

P.S. I know there are cases in which "custom-made" exceptions carry information that latter is used to determine the correct approach to solve the problem...
However, if you think about it, cases like that can, very often (not always, but often), be re-done to throw & catch multiple different tag-classes instead of just a single one (with "content").

Comment: For fun, your coworkers will love you for it, you can also just throw string literals or integers. It's not required to throw objects at all.

Comment: The main difference is that `std::exception` has `what`, so in case of catching `std::exception &`, you can print/log some info about it. If you `catch (...)`, you cannot print/log it in a standard conformant way. If you don't care about this, feel free to use your own exception classes.

Comment: @john Well, those are objects too :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe in Java. Int is not a class or object in c++.

Comment: @lalala The opposite, actually. The C++ standard uses the term "object" to refer to values of any type at all, including non-class types: anything that has a storage location. Java does no such thing, and uses "object" to mean "an instance of a class", which does *not* include ints.

Comment: @amalloy thanks! Always thought of objects as instances of classes. Now I know.it is non 'standard'

Comment: @John I hate you.... and a coworker who may or may not have successfully promoted the use of `throw -1` at a workplace I may or may not have worked at...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, nothing stops you from doing this.

However, some code that wants to catch "any exception" will catch `const std::exception&`, and if your exception type doesn't derive from `std::exception` then that won't work.

Sure, we can catch `...` instead but that's, in my experience, used as a last-ditch "blunt instrument" for avoiding termination due to uncaught exceptions, and can't tell you anything about the exception itself.

<strike>Boost exceptions don't derive from `std::exception` and it's *really annoying*.</strike>

Why not just make all the exceptions part of this standard hierarchy?

If you don't intend to ever let your exception types make get all the way to the top, then there may not be a practical problem here. But, why take the chance? You lose nothing by adding `: std::runtime_error` or somesuch, and the text string that you'll pass to the base is useful information for the diagnosing programmer.

Comment: tl;dr: the benefit of using std::exception is that I will then be able to approve your pull request ;)

Comment: Yes... I completely forget it is easier to just `catch(const std::exception& e)` instead of something like `catch(const out_of_bounds_access& e)`. + the case of `e.what()` Thank you very much!

Comment: "Boost exceptions don't derive from `std::exception` and it's really annoying." – You're meant to use [`boost::throw_exception`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html) which enables a "normal" catch: "The emitted exception can be intercepted as `E &`, `std::exception &`, or `boost::exception &`."; I'm not defending the design decision, but they do have some magic that "fixes" things.

Comment: @ArneVogel Ah, bollocks. Do you think it's too late to raise a bug at my old company? :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Depends on *how* old. It was post-dotcom bust, right? ;-) … @cukier9a7b5: BTW, in addition to `ex.what()` you can use `typeid(ex).name()`, which will give you the mangled type name of the most derived object (because `std::exception` has virtual methods). This can at least be useful for debug logging. In theory, you could even have associative container of handlers (keyed on `std::type_index`) – but don't overdesign it.

Comment: @ArneVogel i knew that something like `typeid()` exists, but tbh I would never come up with the idea to use it in this context. "[...] but don't overdesign it." hehe... well I actually was working on an error-logger (nothing fancy, just basic singleton logger + "error-aware" design around it)... to say the least, I can't promise ^^ Now that you gave me a terrific idea, well... I just want to implement it. Thx!